# Multiple select send by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, select

I have a function called "Nationality". This function pushes selected options into an array from multiple select.
It works great.

But I need to save the array from this function in a variable like this:
`var select = Nationality('NationalityOfOwner');` and then send them into the AJAX function filter_data.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        filter_data();

        function filter_data()
        {
            $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
            var action = 'fetch_data';

            // var Nationality = Nationality('NationalityOfOwner');
            // console.log(Nationality);

            $.ajax({
                url:"includes/filters.inc.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action, Nationality:Nationality},
                success:function(data){
                    $('.filter_data').html(data);
                }
            });

        }

        function Nationality(select){
            $('#'+select).on('change',function(){
                var filter = [];
                $(this).find("option:selected").each(function()
                {
                    filter.push($(this).val());

                });
                console.log(filter);
                return filter;
            });

        }

        var select = Nationality('NationalityOfOwner');
        console.log()
    });


</script>
```

Comment: A return in an event handler has nowhere to return to. Also the event needs to occur before you try to get user input. One other point is if the `<select>` is `multiple` using `val()` on the `select` will already return an array

Comment: But if i change position of return down, its write my "filter is not define".
I'm a beginner in javascript, can you please write more about it? Its select from javascript call "selectpicker".